# Remove element from arraylist which contains all the characters of same type

Tags: java, arraylist

What will be the best way to remove any item from the arraylist, which contains all the characters of the same type?

Please refer the example string array list data below:
Element 1: FFFFFFFF
Element 2: 123
Element 3: ABCD1234
Element 4: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Element 5: ABCDEF
From the above data, I want to remove 1st and 4th records because they contain all the characters as "F".

What I have tried so far is explained in pseudo-code below:
1. Iterated the list till the end in a loop
2. Get the data of current element
3. Check if the element string contains all "F" characters and nothing else.
4. If yes, note the index position of current element else move to next element
5. Use second loop to remove the elements from the stored index position
6. Here I got stuck because removing an element from arraylist changes its size and index position of remaining elements

Note# It will be more helpful if the method is dynamic to supply any character(like if the element contains all "A").

Comment: You have undoubtedly tried a number of possible solutions before posting here. Please add these to your question and clarify what's not working.

Comment: All characters of the *same* type, or of one *specific* type?

Comment: Please explain to me why 4 downvotes.

Comment: If no one bothers to explain the reason of downvoting, before downvoting then I should not use SO anymore.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i've not posted code because I'm not interested in code part. I'm interested in logic part. Because for my need, performance is key component.

Comment: @Aman If you're interested in the logic part: iterate over list, check entry, remove entry if all the characters are the same. As to why you are getting downvoted: if you hover over the downvote link, the tooltip says *"This question does not show any research effort [...]"*. I would have to say that this indeed applies to your question. You basically just list your requirements and show no indication of any effort on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`List.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) with a regex to test for repeating characters:

```
listOfData.removeIf(s -> s.matches("(.)\\1*"));
```

To break down the regex:

- `.` matches any character
- `(.)` captures that first character
- `\1` backreferences that capture
- `*` finds 0 or more of the same

In other words, if the string consists of only a character followed by itself *n* times, remove it.

If you want to test for a *specific* repeating character, say `c`, it's even easier:

```
listOfData.removeIf(s -> s.matches(c + "+"));
```

This means "match one or more instances of `c`". Note that this doesn't handle special characters like `'('`.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is "s" here?

Comment: I have used "(F)" in place of "(.)". Also I read i can place any character here as per my the need I mentioned in the note. Working exactly what I want. Thanks for the time and help. :-)

Comment: You don't need the first solution to match a specific character, as I said. Just do `"F+"`.

Comment: s.matches("(F)\\1*")), this sequence is working as per my need.

Comment: I know, but it's a backwards way of doing some quite simple.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you what you want to say. :-(

Comment: The backreference (`\1`) is only necessary when you're trying to match an unspecified character. If you know which character you're looking for, just specify it: `s.matches("F+")`

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s=//populate data of string here
 int distinct = 1 ;

 for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {

        if(s.charAt(0)==s.charAt(j))
        {
            distinct++;

        }
    }  
   if(s.length==distinct){
  //all characters are same and remove  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you can use `List.removeIf()` as @shmosel suggested. But if you want to compile your code under older java versions, try something like below.

```
public static void removeCharacterSetElementFromList(char character, ArrayList<String> list){
    ArrayList<String> listCopy = (ArrayList<String>)list.clone();
    for (String listItem : listCopy){
        boolean removable = listItem.length()>0 && character==listItem.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < listItem.length(); i++){
            char current = listItem.charAt(i);
            if (character!=current) {
                removable=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(removable) list.remove(listItem);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call `removeCharacterSetElementFromList('F',listOfData);` to remove recodes.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/removing-elements-on-a-list-while-iterating-through-it